# Why are my HTML pages opening correctly locally but not from server?

Tags: html, css

I created a series of HTML files that all use the same CSS sheet for styling that I need to put on my schools server. I also have images in an images folder and the structure looks like this:

```
public_html
 |
 +-- index.html
 |    
 +-- css
 |  |  
 |  +-- site.css
 |    
 +-- project1
 |  |  
 |  +-- index.html
 |  +-- account.html
 |  +-- schedule.html
 |  +-- images
 |      |
 |      +-- gargs.PNG
```

I first created all of this from my local machine and it all works fine from there. 
My `schedule.html` file has this for the CSS reference:

`<link href="../css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

It works just fine locally but I need to put this on my schools server, which I have, but when I open it from filezilla, none of the images or styling is there. 
The `public_html/project1/index.html` file has this for the image reference:

`<image src="images/gargs.PNG" title="Axolotl" alt="My axolotl" width="300" height="400">`

I am pretty sure its because I am not using the relative paths correctly, but do you see anything wrong with it? 
Thanks in advance!

**edit: I have also tried this for my image (I thought maybe if I start at the root it would work) `<image src="/public_html/project1/images/gargs.PNG" title="Axolotl" alt="My axolotl" width="300" height="400">`

Comment: Are you sure your directory is as you illustrated it? Because I've just tested in my own server (which also has "public_html") and everything works fine the way you put it in the first place, doesn't need any change unless your directory is different from what you've shown us.

Comment: @tcj you were correct. I didnt realize that you can’t access the files directly from FileZilla for it to work. I have to use a web address on my schools server to see it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```
<link href="../../css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

(you go up * two*  levels before you go into the `css` folder)